# Web service reference with different URL for every user

Tags: visual-studio

I'm creating an application in Visual Studio which uses web reference. The URL for the reference is:

https://nameSurname.website.com/defectsservice.asmx

Here is how I use it in my code:

```
DefectsService.Defect defect = new DefectsService.Defect();
defect.Name = mo.DefectName;
defect.DateFound = DateTime.Now;
noDefect = new DefectsService.DefectHandler().AddDefect(mo.Guid, defect);
//DefectsService is the name of the service which I give when I add the reference
```

I need to make the application like this: the user will enter his URL and his service will be in use. As I can see, the only place where the URL is written in the solution, is in app.config file. But, if I go to 'Show all files', there appear more files with the URL, like configuration.svcinfo, References.cs etc. So, I have a question:

In my solution I have added the service with my name and surname in the URL. If I leave it like that (the service added) and when the user enters his URL, I only change the app.config file, will the code above work like it is for his service, not mine? Or not, because the service already had my URL when I added it?

UPDATE

Here is my code after the suggestion of Wiktor Zychla:

```
class Program : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public Program()
    {
        this.Url = "";//url entered from every user
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DefectsService.Defect d = new DefectsService.Defect();
        defect.Name = mo.DefectName;
        defect.DateFound = DateTime.Now;
        noDefect = new DefectsService.DefectHandler().AddDefect(mo.Guid, defect);
        //DefectsService is the name of the service which I give when I add the reference
    }
}
```

Comment: defectsservice.website.com/nameSurname would be a LOT easier to do...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The service isn't mine, so I can't change it.

Comment: Ah, Sorry wriong end of stick. THis should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473028/how-to-edit-application-configuration-settings-app-config-best-way-to-go

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I can't understand you. Does that mean your first comment isn't for my question?

Comment: Yes tt meant I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, changing service URL at the client side is very easy:

```
DefectsService.Defect defect = new DefectsService.Defect();
defect.Url = "theurlgoeshere";
```

(assuming that your proxy inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`

Comment: How do you mean my proxy inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol. How to make it to inherit from SoapHttpClientProtocol?

Comment: I updated the question, is this what you had on mind? Will this work?

Comment: I mean the `DefectsService.Defect` class. Is it a proxy to your service? If so, it probably already inherits from the mentioned class.

Comment: Well since defect doesn't have a property named Url, I'd say it doesn't inherit from SoapHttpClientProtocol. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963938/server-was-unable-to-process-request-the-specified-security-token-is-invalid