# Server was unable to process request. The specified security token is invalid

Tags: web-services, asmx

Here is my code:

```
DefectsService.DefectHandler dh = new DefectsService.DefectHandler();
dh.Url = "https://myUrl.com/defectservice.asmx";
DefectsService.Defect defect = new DefectsService.Defect();
defect.Name = "some name";
int noDefect = dh.AddDefect(myGuid, defect);
```

I'm adding a web reference with one URL, which then I change in the second line of the code above. The new URL is correct.

But, when it comes to the last line I get the error "Server was unable to process request. The specified security token is invalid.". What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the authentication protocol being used? How is it set up in IIS? This is some problem with the authentication handshake.

Comment: SOAP is not an authentication protocol. How is the security set up in IIS?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well I never did anything in the IIS, so I suppose it's default.

Comment: Is your service not hosted in IIS? What is the setup of the application it resides in? "security token is invalid" doesn't get displayed because of a lack of security setup.