# C# Read Form Properties from File

Tags: c#, forms, file, properties

Is it possible to have a Windows Form read it's properties from a file, be it.txt, .ini, or .xml?

For example, I want *Button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(382, 328);* to be read from a file, so I can customize the size without editing the source.

How could this be done, if possible include an example.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-application

Comment: I don't think that person is asking the same as me.

Comment: You're looking at having a app.config file or settings file in your app from which you can read settings.

Comment: @Mrchief - while the recommended *answer* can end up being the same, the *question* isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have <strike>two</strike> three decent options:

1. Create a single class which you serialize/deserialize
2. Use the app.config to save your form configuration
3. Settings

With a single class, you might have something like:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class FormProperties
{
    // store as public properties
    [XmlElement]
    public Point myButtonLocation {get; set;}
}
```

Then using XmlSerialization, you can save the settings. Note, any properties you store in this class must be serializable to Xml. Check datatypes like `System.Drawing.Point` to determine what can be serialized.

Alternatively, store your form properties in your application's app.config.

Added #3 - Settings
In VS you can use the Settings.Settings to store form control properties.