# C# Database Options

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am working on learning c# better and have never stored data before. I am writing an application that will grab information from the web and I need to store it so the application can use it again at a later time. I am familiar with mysql, like its feature set, but feel that having the end user install an sql server might be a little much. Im not to the point of learning the xml aspects associated with c#. If possible, I am looking for a file based sql type solution as that would minimize the learning curve in that area leaving me room to focus on the language, however I am open to any suggestions. Google has helped a bit but it doesn't know c# as well as you guys do.

Edit: I'm expecting up to 1k records in 4 different tables.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of options you can look at - depending on how much information you want to store and how you plan on accessing it.

You can always read/write to a file.

- Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx
- Write: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

There's also a concept of 'configuration' settings.  It ultimately reads/writes to a file, for you.  Key/value pairs can be very simple to write, but you can also define custom configurations.

- Simple Config: [Simplest way to have a configuration file in a Windows Forms C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application)
- Custom Config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also serialize objects (and persist them to a file).  This is different than reading and writing 'stuff' to a file, in that the Framework will reconstruct the original object and it's state.

- Serialization: [How to save/restore serializable object to/from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file)

You can also use something like SQL Lite.  It allows you to interact with a 'database' but it doesn't require an database install.  It's essentially a database in a file.

- Sample: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/

Of course - you can always host the SQL server yourself and provide access (directly or through a webservice or some other means).

Having said all that, I'm sure I've missed a bunch.

What's 'best' is really going to depend on your requirements.  I see now you are expecting 'four tables' - so it sounds like you've got a relational database in mind.  I'd recommend looking at SQL lite.

Comment: Thank You for a detailed "jumping off" point. Sqlite sounds great for my project.

Comment: Yes I thought the same bt 5K reputation of @rob stops me from posting the comment.. I always respect those who have better reputation them me.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Express is too big for 1k and 4 tables.

You should use either SQLite or SQL CE.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).  SQL Server is fairly standard and easy to learn so it makes sense for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt [SQL Server 2012 Express (free edition)](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) so you can learn how to access data from database.

On top of that use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) to maximize your learning curve for C# and Database Interactions.

A Good [video is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc546556.aspx).

A must read [beginner's guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) is also provide.

Comment: do you know what's the difference between sql server 2012 free edition and sql server express?