# Registry entries for custom service - when to create/remove them?

Tags: c#, .net, service, registry

I am currently making my first attempts at creating a simple Windows Service using C# and .NET. I am at a point where the service does what it is supposed to do, but uses a lot of hard-coded values. I want to move these values to a separate configuration area - probably the Windows registry. I would like to provide my service with a kind of default configuration - if the settings / registry entries aren't present, create a set of default values and warn the user that the default values may need to be adjusted. However, I am unsure on *when* to perform this operation:

- I could create the registry entries from the constructor of the `ServiceBase` descendant.
- I could create the entries within the installer I created following the tutorial (a subclass `System.Configuration.Install.Installer`).

I am unsure whether there are other options, what the pros and cons of these options are and whether there is a "correct" approach to perform this. I am even less sure if and where I should provide code to automatically remove the registry entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the register, you should let the installer to create the default key/values pairs, and let the uninstaller delete them.

Another way is to use the app config file, which is more simple then dealing with registry, See this posts: [Simplest way to have a configuration file in a Windows Forms C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application)

Comment: I need my service to be configurable by the admin who installs it, not at design/compilation time. I'm not sure whether the app config file is the way to go...?

Comment: sure, you can do it with config file