# Where to hide a connection string in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, database-connection, data-access-layer

Where would you recommend hiding or writing a connection string in a winforms desktop app? I have a DAL (data access layer) where I hardcoded it for the time being, but I know it shouldn't be there. Any tips on this? (I'm in VS 2017.)

Comment: put it inside the app.config file

Comment: You can use a configuration file. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Resource file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps#VSResFiles) should work well for this.

Using Visual Studio, you can add one to a project by right-clicking the project and choosing "Properties", then go to the "Resources" tab and either create a default resource file (by clicking the link), or updating the existing resource file using the UI.

Once your project has a default resource file with key-value pairs in it, using values from the resource file in code is as simple as

```
Properties.Resources.AnyKeyYouDefinedInTheResourceFile
```

...where `AnyKeyYouDefinedInTheResourceFile` is a key in the project's default resource file.

Note that the above example assumes that the code snippet is in the default namespace, since the full namespace for `Properties` is really `WhateverYourDefaultNamespaceIsCalled.Properties`.