# Compile App.config XML file along with console.exe application C#

Tags: c#, configuration

Surely I have missed something simple here. I used the link below to help me create a configuration file which I can use in my console application.

[Simplest way to have a configuration file in a Windows Forms C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="setting1" value="key"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have built my console application, but can't see the app.config file anywhere. I'd like to edit this configuration file without recompiling.

Any idea on how to do this ? Basically, I'm passing the compiled console app to someone, and wont be providing the source code, so I have provided an .xml document which I hope they'll be able to edit after the console app has been compiled.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need click on your project in Solution explorer, select `Add File` option and choose app.config.
When you will rebuild solution file will by added configuration file like `your_application.exe.config`

Comment: I knew I was missing something. It's right there in front of me -.- you mentioned the name would be 'your_application.exe.config' and that solved it. Appreciate it, thanks